# C++ Timer not working?

Tags: c++, winapi, native

I'm trying to make a timer in c++. I'm new to c++. I found this code snippet

UINT_PTR SetTimer(HWND hWnd, UINT_PTR nIDEvent, UINT uElapse, TIMERPROC lpTimerFunc);

I put it in my global variables and it tells me

Error   1   error C2373: 'SetTimer' : redefinition; different type modifiers

I'm  not sure what this means. Is there a more proper way to define a timer?

I'm not using mfc / afx

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
void CALLBACK TimerProc(
 HWND hwnd, 
 UINT uMsg, 
 UINT idEvent, 
 DWORD dwTime 
)
{
 //do something
}

SetTimer(NULL, NULL, 1000, TimerProc);
```

This would set a timer for 1 second and will call TimerProc when it expires. Read TimerProc MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644907%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: How it will call function TimerProc if you are passing "OnTimer" in SetTimer??

Comment: Good spot. This answer is almost 4 years old :)

Comment: I want an Excavator badge ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a function call -- that's a function declaration, which you are probably already #including from somewhere.  What you need is the actual SetTimer call from your code.

Can you post your code where you're trying to set up the timer, and the function you want it to call when it triggers?